# Set body in Azure APIM Policy

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management, azure-policy, apim

My incoming payload is

```
{ "data":"testdata"}
```

along with a header X-Type = headerType, I want to map the header into the payload before sending it to the backend system

I want to convert the payload as below

```
{"data":"testdata","type":"headerType"}
```

I tried set body but no luck, can some one help

```
<set-body>@{ 
    var requestBody = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: 
    true);

    requestBody ["type"] = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("X-Type","");

    return requestBody.ToString();
}</set-body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue.

Maybe it's a typo in question or there's really a space in this line:
`requestBody ["type"] =`

Please do not forget to send the header.

For testing purposes, the `set-body` policy is placed inside a `return-response` policy:

Inbound policy:

```xml
<inbound>
    <base />
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="200" reason="ok" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@{
            var requestBody  = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
            requestBody["type"] = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("X-Type","");
            return requestBody.ToString();               
        }</set-body>
    </return-response>
</inbound>
```

Test in API Management with

- header `X-Type` : `lorem`
- request body: `{ "data":"testdata"}`

[image]